# Approximating $\int_1^3 \int_1^3 \int_1^3 x^{y^z} \mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, approximation, volume

I was given a really nasty integral to approximate, which was

$$\int_1^3 \int_1^3 \int_1^3 x^{y^z}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz$$

I was completely clueless; and my interviewer gave me some hints but I got nowhere. I was told that the order of magnitude is roughly $10^9$. Could someone help me out? Thank you!

Comment: Note that $\int_1^3 \int_1^3 \int_1^3 x^{y^z} \text{d}x \text{d}y \text{d}z\leq (3-1) \int_1^3 \int_1^3 x^{y^3}\text{d}x \text{d}y$.

Comment: Also $\int a^x\,dx=\frac{a^x}{\ln a}+c$

Comment: are there any substitutions that work? e.g.$v=x^u$ and $u=y^z$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the integrand gets huge at the $(3,3,3)$ corner.  At that point it is $3^{27}\approx 7.6\cdot 10^{12}$.  Most of the contribution will come from near that point, so you want to form some estimate of how much volume there is where the integrand is large.

I think I would arbitrarily try to find how far you have to move in each direction to reduce the integrand by a factor $9$.  In the $y,z$ directions that means reducing $y^z$ to $25$.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(3,25)) tells me that $\log_3(25) \approx 2.93$ and 
$25^{1/3}\approx 2.92$.  Finally for $x$ we want $x_0^{27}=3^{25}$ and we find $(3^{25})^{(1/27)}\approx 2.77$, so our integrand is large in a volume of $0.07\cdot 0.08 \cdot 0.23 \approx 0.0013$.  This is really too large because the bottom corner has three factors of $9$ divided out, but using it the integral is somewhere near $3^{26}\cdot 0.0013\approx 3\cdot 10^9$  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%20x%5E(y%5Ez)%20,%7Bx,2.7,3%7D,%7By,2.9,3%7D,%7Bz,2.9,3%7D) did it when I reduced the range in $x$ to $[2.7,3]$ and in $y,z$ to $[2.9,3]$.  It gave $8.2\cdot 10^8$ for the integral of that small volume, which includes all of mine.

I should probably use the volume of a tetrahedron instead of a box, which divided my estimate by $6$, but that is an afterthought.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t follow your second paragraph, could you explain in a bit more in detail?

Comment: I am just approximating the volume over which the integrand is greater than $3^{25}$, then using $3^{26}$ times that volume to estimate the integral.  I calculate how much you need to decrease each of $x,y,z$ to get the integrand down to $3^{25}$ while keeping the others constant, to make a box.  For $y$ and $z$ we want $y^z=25$.  The first calculation is that $3^{2.93}=25$ and the second that $2.92^3}=25, so our box in $z$ is $[2.93,3]$ and in $y$ is $[2,92,3]$